# Powershell - Comparing get-variable outputs and displaying if any values change

Tags: powershell, compareobject

Hi I hope someone can point me in the correct direction here.

I am trying to create some PS 5.1 code that can compare get-variable output at the start of a script with get-variable output generated when there is a error.

I would like to display name-value object information only if a new variable is created OR if its value differs from that generated at the start of the script.

I thought this would be fairly easy using compare-object but i am having difficulty getting this to work with value changes:

```
$PostscriptVar = Get-Variable
$NewVar1 = 1
$Avarchange = Get-Date
$EndscriptVar  = get-variable

#This works for any new variables created.
compare-object $PostscriptVar $EndscriptVar -Property name

#This doesn't work for any change in values - i can't get this to work.
#compare-object $PostscriptVar $EndscriptVar -Property name,value
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but it seems to work if I only select the `Name` and `Value` properties from `Get-Variable`

```
Remove-Variable NewVar1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$Avarchange = Get-Date
$PostscriptVar = Get-Variable | Select-Object Name, Value
$NewVar1 = 1
$Avarchange = $Avarchange.AddDays(1)
$EndscriptVar = Get-Variable | Select-Object Name, Value

Compare-Object $PostscriptVar $EndscriptVar -Property Name, Value
```

Comment: Thanks very much that works great, i have no idea either - i'll have to note that down as that had me stumped for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Final Code i used for anyone interested based on Daniels comment above.

```
$PrescriptVar = Get-Variable | Select-Object Name, Value
$NewVar6 = 2
$arraytest = "test1","Test2","Test3"
$Avarchange = $Avarchange.AddDays(1)
$EndscriptVar = Get-Variable | Select-Object Name, Value

#Compare-Object $PrescriptVar $EndscriptVar -Property Name, Value
$NewOrChangedVarObj = Compare-Object $PrescriptVar $EndscriptVar -Property Name, Value | ?{$_.sideindicator -eq '=>'} | Where -Property Name -ne "PrescriptVar" | Where -Property Name -ne "EndscriptVar"

$NewOrChangedVarObj | Select-Object Name, Value | fl
```